# PHP json_encode makes object, not array

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

I have the following PHP code which accesses DB functions, takes the response and encodes that to JSON.

Its supposed to make an error object and then an array containing all returned database rows.

```
$key = $db->getKeyPermissions();

    if ($key != false) {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
        $response["key"] = array();    
        $response["key"]["endpoint_description"] = $key[$i]["endpoint_description"];
        $response["key"]["live"] = $key[$i]["live"];
        $response["key"]["activity_name"] = $key[$i]["activity_name"];

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

instead of echo'ing a list of around 13 items, it only echos the very last item as an object. What am I doing wrong? How can I turn "key" object into a list containing all keys.

This is the JSON output.

```
{
  "error": false,
  "key": {
    "endpoint_description": "Guilds' rosters, history, and MOTDs for all guilds you are a member of.",
    "live": 0,
    "activity_name": ""
  }
}
```

Im fairly sure this is how it's supposed to look like, how I need it.

```
{
  "error": false,
  "key": [
    {
      "endpoint_description": "Guilds' rosters, history, and MOTDs for all guilds you are a member of.",
      "live": 0,
      "activity_name": ""
    },
    {
      "endpoint_description": "Guilds' rosters, history, and MOTDs for all guilds you are a member of.",
      "live": 0,
      "activity_name": ""
    },
    {
      "endpoint_description": "Guilds' rosters, history, and MOTDs for all guilds you are a member of.",
      "live": 0,
      "activity_name": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In the loop you reset the response keys, like `$response['key']['live']` on every iteration. You probably want these to be `$response['key'][$i]['live']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key = $db->getKeyPermissions();

if ($key != false) {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
    $response["key"][$i] = array();    
    $response["key"][$i]["endpoint_description"] = $key[$i]["endpoint_description"];
    $response["key"][$i]["live"] = $key[$i]["live"];
    $response["key"][$i]["activity_name"] = $key[$i]["activity_name"];

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

This should work as expected [$i] was missing.As per your requirement usage can be like

> $response["key"][$i]

Please check

Comment: I have edited my question, at very bottom I added a code block of what I think the JSON should look like in order to have it properly work for what I need. You think thats possible? because i dont think this will for me.

Comment: Your code does work, it does return all rows, but It creates a new object within the list, I dont think that works for me.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Already tried it before your comment but couldnt accept it as an answer yet :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = $db->getKeyPermissions();

if ($key != false) {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["key"] = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
    $response["key"][] = [
       "endpoint_description" => $key[$i]["endpoint_description"],
       "live" => $key[$i]["live"],
       "activity_name" => $key[$i]["activity_name"]
    ];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```